# Cannot install gifted chat UI using npm

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

When I am trying to install a gifted chat UI package, it is returning me an error that it does not exist. Can you please help me to resolve this?

- Node ver: 10
- React Native ver:0.61
- Android

`C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\AProject>npm i react-native-gifted-chat
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t         https://github.com/EvanBacon/react-native-parsed-text.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-17T05_42_35_768Z-debug.log`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use git bash to install gifted chat . I have answered this question here.

https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1444

Install git and then from git console install gifted chat .